# Promise resolve output message will empty. How to solve the problem

Tags: promise

In backend program, i use new Promise(resolve, reject). When it success post data to database, it will output empty. How make it output "success！ article_id: 1"?

```
const createArticle = (insertValues) => 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
        connectionPool.getConnection((connectionError, connection) =>
        {
            if(connectionError)
            {
                reject(connectionError);
            }
            else
            {
                connection.query('Insert into Article set?', insertValues, (error, result) => 
                {
                    if(error)
                    {
                        console.error('sql error: ', error);
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    else if (result.affectedRows === 1)
                    {
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                        resolve(`success！ article_id: ${result.insertId}`);
                       
                    }
                    
                    connection.release();
                    
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

i use the program to call createArticle.

```
const articlePost = (req, res) => 
{
    const insertValues = req.body;
    articleModule.createArticle(insertValues).then((result) =>{
        res.sent(result);
    }).catch((err) => { return res.send(err); });
};
```

Comment: Please show the entire function of code.  What you've shown here is not enough for us to understand what the problem is or really even what the question is.  You may also need to show how the `createArticle()` function is called so we can see where the "output" is that you refer to.

Comment: Can you share your entity?

Comment: my progam store different code in different file. so, i can not share my program.

Comment: The code shown here works just fine. If there is one row inserted it will resolve with the success message. Can you show how you call this function? And how you use the result of the promise?

Comment: One issue I notice is that if `result.affectedRows` is not `1`, and there's no other error, then you NEVER resolve or reject your promise.  You need an `else` condition so you are resolving your promise when `result.affectedRows` is not `1`.

Comment: result.affectedRows can output other number. My question give a example to output.

Comment: what is `res.sent(...)` you probably mean `res.send(result)` ...

Comment: i change from res.sent(...) to res.send(result). It will output message. Thank you.